# I am trying to add +1 whenever i click on a button Add - invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sessions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sessions'

***MYCODE***

```
def subs(request, pk):
    sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values('sessions').first()
    sw_list = list(map(int, sw ))
    sw_lists = list(map(lambda x: x + 1, sw_list ))
    return JsonResponse(list(sw_lists), safe=False)
```

Comment: you're converting a 'sessions' string to an integer check your `sw` share it

Comment: This is my sw

class Swimmers(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
 lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
 idno = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
 sessions = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
 totalsessions = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False )
 registration = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
 keenphone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.name

Comment: I meant the data itself not the model

Comment: I checked my database, kindly what am i looking for, my sw table has a sessions column with integer fields

Comment: Thank You for taking your time to reply back

Comment: strange must be something wrong with returned data could you add a print statement and print the sw variable?

Comment: When i print sw i get sw_list = list(map(int, sw)) in the debugger i can see sw output session 15

Comment: This was my idea at first but i get an error

def subs(request, pk):
 sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values('sessions').first()
 sw_list =  sw
 sw_lists = sw + 1
 return JsonResponse(sw_lists safe=False)

Comment: I Flushed my data table with no luck still get a base10 error

Comment: the error is not because of the data in the database it's because of the object you're trying to fetch and convert and it's probably a string, not an integer maybe it's an integer try `sw_list = list(map(int, float(sw)))` and just PRINT THE SW VARIABLE and put the results here

Comment: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict' .
Thank YOU for the fast reply, May YOU HAVE A BLESSED DAY.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have managed to solve the error by adding `.values_list` in my queryset as `.values` was outputting sessions as a `string`.

**My code:**

```
def subs(request, pk):
    sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values_list('sessions').first()
    sw_list = list(map(int, sw))
    sw_lists = list(map(lambda x: x + 10, sw_list ))
    return JsonResponse(list(sw_lists), safe=False)
```